# multinomial coefficient

Tags: statistics

Twenty-five girls are bored.

a) In how many ways may five girls be chosen to go to a party and five different girls be chosen to volunteer at a soup kitchen (and the remaining 15 girls stay home)?

b) How many ways may the girls form two teams of 5 to play basketball against each other?

---

I got answer a) by using the multinomial coefficient $\binom{25}{5,5,15} = 8.23*10^8$

I tried this with b) as well but the answer is $4.11*10^8$. I attempted $\binom{25}{10,15}$, but I still got the wrong answer.

Can someone explain why the two answers are different?

Answer (score 1):

In (a), the groups are distinct (labelled *party* and *soup kitchen*)

For (b), since there is no indication that the teams are labelled, we treat them as unlabelled, so ABCDE | FGHIJ is the same as FGHIJ | ABCDE

Comment: how would I set this up mathematical? It seems similar to \binom{25}{10,15}. What difference am I missing?

Comment: ${25\choose5}{20\choose5}/2! $ Or ${25\choose 5,5,15}/2!$

Comment: So it's divided by the factorial of indistinguishable groups? For example, if I wanted three teams it would be \binom{25}{5,5,5,10}/3!

Comment: That is a correct understanding.

Answer (score 0):

(b) Try
\begin{align}
\binom{25}{5}*\binom{20}{5}
\\= \frac{25!}{5!20!}*\frac{20!}{5!15!}
\\= \frac{25!}{5!5!15!}
\end{align}

Comment: that gives the answer to part a), but not part b). This is what I've already tried.